# Cross-controller Virtual Attribute

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to have an application wide virtual attribute without the use of a session.

For example, I already have a session for a current_use

- Given the user manages Organization A & B
- When the user selects "Organization A" and visits "Add a new member" then he should see "Add a new member to Organization A"

-If he returs to the home screen and selects "Organization B" then the new member view should read "Add a new member to Organization B"

In reality, there are roughly 8 controllers that would need to accept this attribute. Should this be tackled with attribute accessor?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new session based on the ID of the "Organization" then just made sure to destroy the previous session whenever a new org is selected. Seems to be working fine.